# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS won't install - never finishes please help

Tags: 12.04, installation

Want to try Ubuntu after using Windows for 30 years. Tried to install it 5 times on a Lenovo X120e notebook and twice on a Lenovo M57 desktop. No luck, worse than what Microsoft puts you through.

I burned 12.04 LTS to disc. It installs up to the "Who Are You?" screen, then stops. Accepted the recommended computer name and lower case user name. I chose "log me in automatically." After that there is no progress bar, no rotating or pulsing button, nothing to indicate the Ubuntu has not died or fallen asleep. Is that how it is written? Never heard of a program that would take a long time to install while a user looked at a locked, dead screen.

I just bought the M57 desktop for my son. It came with Ubuntu 10 something. I wanted to upgrade to 12.04 but it crashed, twice, to a DOS screen saying the pc lacked a certain "init" file. Various help screen commands did not help.

On the X120e, I thought a partial-failed Ubuntu install was causing the problem, so I removed the drive and deleted the Ubuntu partition and replaced it. But same result. After I fill in my name, accept computer and user name, the "continue" button does not appear to work. I can go "back" but not forward.

I have waited torturous hours. It doesn't take more than two hours to install, does it?any

It is my own fault because of the high expectations I had for a sensible, hassle-free installation, but I am immensely disappointed.

Thank you for any response

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear as though Ubuntu is supported with your hardware according to the official Ubuntu certified hardware list found here:

[http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Lenovo/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=8OAcWFmhefE8uYSbG9FS6X8qcd29VrrO&query=lenovo+m57&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Server&release=&level=Any](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Lenovo/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=8OAcWFmhefE8uYSbG9FS6X8qcd29VrrO&query=lenovo%20m57&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Server&release=&level=Any)

However, this does not mean that it is impossible to install on this particular unit.

I would first try the alternative install image or maybe even a previous release found here:
 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Are there any error messages that you are receiving while installing?